# Trying to iterate through ListBox, Error : Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, loops

I have a method in another class i'm using to send data to a database. That method is [here](http://pastebin.com/0e0D5GTd) as well.

```
public Int32 AddOrder(clsStock NewItem)
{
    //this function takes the data passed via NewItem
    //and passes it to the parameters for the stored procedure
    //
    //create an instance of the data dictionary
    clsDataDictionary DD = new clsDataDictionary();
    //create an instance of the object class
    Int32 ReturnValue;
    //create an instance of the data conduit
    clsDataConduit Items = new clsDataConduit();
    //pass the data for this address
    Items.AddParameter(DD.sproc_tblOrders_Add_AuthId, NewItem.AuthId);
    Items.AddParameter(DD.sproc_tblOrders_Add_ItemId, NewItem.ItemId);
    Items.AddParameter(DD.sproc_tblOrders_Add_DateOrdered, NewItem.DateOrdered);
    Items.AddParameter(DD.sproc_tblOrders_Add_Cancel, NewItem.Cancel);
    //execute the stored procedure
    ReturnValue = Items.Execute(DD.sproc_tblOrders_Add);
    //return the primary key value
    return ReturnValue;
}
```

The method on my aspx page which i'm using to iterate through my listbox and execute that method for each item in the listbox is [here](http://pastebin.com/WKSBev2P) as well.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create an instance of the collection class
    clsStockCollection Items = new clsStockCollection();

    foreach(int id in lstAdded.Items)
    {
        TheItem.AuthId = 5;
        TheItem.ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(lstAdded.Items[id].Value);
        TheItem.Cancel = "false";
        Items.AddOrder(TheItem);
    }
    Response.Redirect("Order.aspx");
}
```

When I run my website and hit the btnSubmit it's giving the following error :

`"Specified cast is not valid"` that is on the method on the `aspx` page (the 2nd pastebin file)

Any idea why this is?

Comment: its better if you post the code in your question in the code blocks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
foreach(ListItem item in lstAdded.Items)
{
    TheItem = new clsStock();
    TheItem.AuthId = 5;
    TheItem.ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
    TheItem.Cancel = "false";
    Items.AddOrder(TheItem);
}
```

Comment: This is the way it worked! Thanks for everyones input. I don't have enough reputation otherwise I would be upvoting all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the [ListBox.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx) through an `int` type field. ListBox.Items is a `ListItemCollection`, what you can do is use implicitly typed variable using `var` keyword, like:

```
foreach(var id in lstAdded.Items)
{
    TheItem.AuthId = 5;
    TheItem.ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(id.Text); //Change here
    TheItem.Cancel = "false";
    Items.AddOrder(TheItem);
}
```

Currently it appears you are considering it as an index in `foreach` loop, instead its a single item from the `lstAdded`

Comment: Thanks for this reply @Habib and I noticed you edited my question aswell. I will keep that in mind, about posting my code in code blocks when it's not too much code :)